# jUnit tests won't recognize source files in cloned Netbeans project

Tags: netbeans, github, junit

I have a project with jUnit tests that I created on a school computer with Netbeans 7.3. The 
unit tests run great there. I have it committed to a github repository. At home I have Netbeans 7.4. I used `Team->Git->Clone` to clone the project down to my home computer. The project was created just fine, but all of my unit tests are flagged as "Duplicate Class."

If it works on one computer but not another, how do I trouble-shoot this?

I used Netbeans to initialize the Git Repository. Committed and pushed all my code to git hub. The GitHub repository has a copy of the nbproject folder. Both the school and home computer have junit4 installed. What am I missing?

The repo is here for anyone that wants to look: https://github.com/mmeier/Java113.git

### UPDATE

Unit tests run just fine on the home computer. However the IDE is still displaying errors. Clearly a configuration issue, but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was causing the problem but here's how I finally resolved it.

1. Uninstall/Reinstall NetBeans
2. Create new basic Java Application (create new project wizard)
3. Add new jUnit test for existing class.
4. When prompted, select to install jUnit 4
5. Clone project from GitHub as described in question.
6. Delete temp project created in step 2.

Feels like I'm doing a work-around. But for some reason cloning the project and then installing jUnit 4 didn't appear to work.